# Error: SELECT bookedseat from bookings where sdate=2018-04-26 and stime=5PM Unknown column '5PM' in 'where clause'

Tags: php

[This is the html form code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkpo4.jpg)

[And this is the php for the above form.After executing this,I get an error saying " Error: SELECT bookedseat from bookings where sdate=2018-04-26 and stime=5PM
Unknown column '5PM' in 'where clause' "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiYlQ.jpg)

Why is it?

Comment: Bind your input to prepared statements rather than concatenating it into your SQL string, and you'll avoid a lot of these kinds of problems, among other things. And please include your code in the question instead of links to pictures of your code.

Comment: MySQL thinks 5PM is a column identifier because it isn't quoted. But you shouldn't fix it by quoting it, you should use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Code is made of _text_. Text is great! Code should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to crappy image formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your variables in single quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT bookedseat from bookings where sdate='$sdate' and stime='$stime'"
```

PD: As everybody says, this is not the best approach. You need to make a prepared statement instead to avoid sql injection and other type of errors like this